# Alternative to static nested classes in C# for grouping a classes public methods?

Tags: c#, sql, database, select

I am attempting to create an internet accessible business object database layer.

I would like to call the database accessor methods like the following:

```
_databaseHander.Employee.SelectBetweenDates(date1, date2);
_databaseHandler.PayDetails.SelectAll();
_databaseHandler.BusinessArea.InsertAll(businessAreaData);
```

called via HTTP this would get translated to the following:

```
www.website.com/DatabaseObject/Employee/SelectBetweenDates/Date1=yyyyMMdd&Date2=yyyyMMdd
www.website.com/DatabaseObject/BusinessArea/InsertAll (will be sent as a post)
```

I am unsure how this would be done. I would expect it would be something like the following:

```
public class DatabaseHandler
{
    private DatabaseContext _context;
    public DatabaseHandler(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public static class Employee
    {
        public static IEnumerable<EmployeeData> SelectBetweenDates(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
        {
            return _context.Select(x=>x.FromDate <=date1 && x.ToDate>=date2);
        }
    }
}
```

This seems like a misuse of 'static'... And am not even sure if it's possible to code this way. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could proceed?

The reasons I am attempting to split up the method calls is so that the auto-complete is useful ie. typing _databaseHandler. will not return 4 or 5 methods per database object.

I would also like to split the class up into partial classes for better readability to avoid a 10,000 line class.

Comment: Well currently you've got a static class but you're accessing it through a reference, so that won't work. You could create a *property* called `Employee` which returns an instance of some appropriate class, which could be a top-level class.

Comment: That's an amazing idea! That's just what I needed. It's so simple. Please rewrite this comment as an answer so I can accept it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate class, which can be non-nested - then have a *property* in `DatabaseHandler` which returns an instance.

I don't think this should actually be called `Employee` however, as it clearly doesn't represent an *individual* employee. It's more of an `EmployeeCollection`. To be honest, you could potentially just return an `IQueryable<EmployeeData>` (I'm assuming this is LINQ-based), and then add *extension* methods in a separate static class to add collection-specific queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
Employee theEmployee = new Employee();
```

Would give you an `Employee` object to work with.

With this you could change the values of the `Employee` class from `DataBaseHandler`